Gaussian Program Error for Linear Triatomic Molecule
I am trying to calculate the Hessian and vibrational frequencies of OCS (and eventually some anharmonic properties) with Gaussian09. However, the program always fails and I end up with the following error message:
Molecule is linear but NTrRo=6 and XMin = 1.97D-07
Error termination via Lnk1e in .../gaussian/g09/l716.exe at ...

(the ellipses represent the exact location and date, respectively)
The following is the input file I am trying to submit:
# B3LYP/Def2TZVPP Opt(Cartesian) Freq SCF(Tight)

0 1
C -5.911367e-05 0.00000 0.52489722
S 9.4364088e-06 1.0571526e-15 -1.037775
O 2.5504285e-05 2.856947239e-15 1.680603306

What I find weird is that I tested running HCN with the exact same keywords, and even though I get the same error it actually continues running and it finishes "normally" according to Gaussian.
I am not sure about the XMin part, but I'm othewise guessing that I'm running into issues because of the double degeneracy of two normal modes; it calculates both of them to be exactly identical (at least, to the amount of significant figures that it displays), whereas for HCN, the frequencies are not calculated to be exactly identical (although I believe they should be if it's perfectly linear).
How do I get around this? Can I get around this? If this is really a limitation of Gaussian, I find it odd, since I feel like someone must have calculated the frequencies of e.g. CO2 at some point with Gaussian?
P.S. I'm a beginner with these kinds of calculations, so I could imagine that maybe the level of theory I'm using isn't ideal (e.g. my functional and basis set), but so far for all of my systems it's been working well, so I can't imagine why this would all of a sudden be the cause of my problems.

What happens if you add the nosymm keyword to the input line?
